# What is [winapp]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

What is [winapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapp)?

If it's a ***thing***, can someone add tag info, please?

---

Any hints of what should happen? Shall I edit wiki myself (never did it)? Should it stay like it is? Should it be burninated?

Did I do a wrong thing to ask on meta and should rather just ignore tags I don't understand and without info?

Comment: Currently tagged oldest-and-visible-publicly question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378134/how-to-delete-a-file-used-by-other-process. Looks like a common term for "Windows desktop application", e.g. WinForms, WPF...

Comment: @AndrewT., thanks. Haven't thought to check very first post to figure it out.

Comment: Well, that's the question that needs to be followed up and discussed with the community though... the term "WinApp" itself is not really popular on Google (or I failed miserably with how a search engine works), resulting in different expectation.

Comment: Seems like at least a part of these questions refer to appium and their winapp driver, if it's just _an application for Windows_ it could get added as a synonym of [tag:windows]

Comment: Looks like [it was a popular term in the 90s and in the early aughts](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&content=WinApp&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWinApp%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CWinApp%3B%2Cc0), in books, anyway....

Comment: Other possible candidates: [One](https://www.softwareadvice.com/medical/winapps-profile/); [Two](https://pypi.org/project/winapps/); [Three](https://www.file.net/process/winapp.exe.html)

Comment: Regarding "Did I did a wrong think..." first you should ask your self why are you interested in that tag / what motivated you to post this question.

Comment: Tags should reflect what a question is _about_. There are only 85 questions with that tag, and skimming through the list, it seems to me that few if any are actually _about_ "Windows application", even if we assume that's what the tag is supposed to mean, and if we're generous about a question being _about_ that. Given that in all this time, no one has seen fit to actually _define_ the tag, and all these other factors, it's hard to imagine there being any real harm to the site in removing it, and some significant benefit. ...

Comment: ... Alternatively, write a description (i.e. _decide_ what it should actually mean) and then remove it from any post where it doesn't strictly qualify.

Comment: I say remove the useless tag. The term WinApp is too broad and unclear. We have _console, winforms, wpf_ and _uwp_ for windows application. Also if a question is related to the OS itself, then the tag should be _windows_.

Comment: @DanielWu that sounds more like an answer than a comment.

Comment: @Rubén, I just stamble at [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63411186/1997232) of the recent questions using this tag. Since I didn't have a clear idea what is it, I check tag wiki and found nothing. Think about my question as problem report.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A [winapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapp) is, obviously<sup>1</sup>, a Windows Application!

I won't be writing the tag info, however, as the tag probably shouldn't exist.  I just went through all 85 questions on this tag to summarize what they meant, and got the following distribution:

- 56 were referring to a windows application in a generic sense, the windows API, or Microsoft Office products.  The largest portion of these related to C# / .NET / Visual Studio development, which would include primarily WPF or Windows Forms apps.
- 19 specifically mentioned [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) or Winforms
- 4 referred to UWP / [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) apps
- 4 referred to [winappdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winappdriver) associated with appium
- 2 referred to python modules with "winapp" in their names.

I did find at least one tagged with [windows-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-applications) which was a synonym for [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), and seems an appropriate solution for this tag if it is not otherwise associated with [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf).

---

<sup>1</sup> - Not really that obvious. While that may be the obvious parsing of the abbreviations "win" and "app" it does not necessarily mean that's the obvious specific meaning of the combined term.

Comment: Yuck. Winapp really is the old name for windows runtime, but almost everybody used the tag wrong (assuming the tag matches the name of thing).

Comment: Regarding *"obviously"*: I am developing desktop applications for Windows during last 20 years and I don't recognize winapp term. Winapi, windows, application... but winapp?

Comment: I'd never heard of the term either, but "win" is pretty much always windows and "app" is pretty much application.  Perhaps it's not obvious that's what it means *here*, of course.